# Postgresql missing FROM-entry for table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables

- messages
- respondents

and I'm trying to join them using a simple inner join query

```
SELECT
  Message.content,
  Message.created_at,
  Respondent.name 
FROM
  MESSAGES
  INNER JOIN RESPONDENTS ON Message.respondent_id = Respondent.id;
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "message"
LINE 1: ...dent.name FROM MESSAGES INNER JOIN RESPONDENTS ON Message.re...
```

Can anyone help me out??

Comment: `MESSAGES ` is not the same as `Message`.

Comment: and that's all it took to fix it....thanks forpas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two typos in your query. Try this - assuming your tables are called `respondents` and `messages`:

```
SELECT 
  messages.content, messages.created_at, respondents.name 
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN respondents ON messages.respondent_id = respondents.id;
```